# Ayuda con Moodle 3.5 y sus extensiones

Tags: moodle

estoy con un trabajo que me pidieron para una plataforma en moodle.. Tengo que hacer un plugin de envio masivo de correos automaticos a todos los alumnos que reprobaron el curso...
Lo que si, nunca en mi vida toque moodle pero igual acepte el trabajo... Lo primero que hice fue descargar moodle en mi maquina para trabajar... despues empece a descargar algunos plugins como por ejemplo Quick mail para ver su funcionamiento. Pero ya no puedo avanzar desde aqui.. cuando instalo el plugin no encuentro donde utilizarlo, en todos los tutoriales y docuemntacion que vi me deberia aparecer como un bloque en la derecha de mi maquina.. alguna ayuda o consejo?? 
Estoy usando moodle 3.5

Comment: Para desarrollar un plugin de moodle hay que entender varias cosas antes de siquiera elegir el tipo de plugin, cada tipo de plugin tiene un ámbito y funcionalidad diferente dependiendo de tus necesidades.
Tu pregunta es extremadamente amplia, primero revisa [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), revisa que tipo de plugin se adapta a tus necesidades y parte preguntando desde ahí [Tipos de plugin en moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types)